# Melt data for one column

Tags: r, reshape

I have this data:

```
 datetime stock
 2010-01-01 4
 2010-01-02 7
 2010-01-03 2
 2010-01-04 9
```

And I want to make this output:

```
 datetime stock val
 2010-01-01 4    stock
 2010-01-02 7    stock
 2010-01-03 2    stock
 2010-01-04 9    stock
```

I tried to melt the data but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you tried, but both of the following options work for me.

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

Option 1: `stack` from Base R

```
cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1]))
#     datetime values   ind
# 1 2010-01-01      4 stock
# 2 2010-01-02      7 stock
# 3 2010-01-03      2 stock
# 4 2010-01-04      9 stock
```

Option 2: `melt` from "reshape2"

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mydf, id.vars="datetime")
#     datetime variable value
# 1 2010-01-01    stock     4
# 2 2010-01-02    stock     7
# 3 2010-01-03    stock     2
# 4 2010-01-04    stock     9
```